# DLL/TLB in Java<->DCOM communication

Tags: java, c++, dll, dcom

I have to write an OpenOffice add-on (in Java) which communicates with DCOM server of some closed-source application. The major problem is that, I don't have any documentation about server's Interfaces .

All I have is a VB/C++ SDK kit for the Application. SDK contain a library in dll and a bunch of *.tlb files. In SDK documentation there is an information, I can use java, but there is no example at all. I have read provided examples  and it looks like all the communication wit DCOM goes through this dll.

Is there a way to somehow import such dll/tlb functions def directly to java, bypass dll and comunicate with DCOM or I have to write a C++ wrapper(dll)? What is the best way to do it?

Any hints are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a project like [j-Interop](http://j-interop.org/) for communication with (D)COM servers.